# Imperial Assignments not appearing?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

It's been 2 or 3 days since my third slot had an Imperial Assignment in it.  Is this anyone else's experience?  I am 9 hours away from completing the last build of Imperial Levels, except for the Overbridge.  I'm wondering if Imperial Assignments stop or run out...

Comment: I have all 80 upper levels, but none of the current new levels based on probe searches (despite a lot of attempts).  I also have 19 Imperial Levels + 1 almost completed--but not the Overbridge because it is locked.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't had an imperial assignment appear for about 4 days - lord vader appears when I click on them and tells me to be patient. I assume I've completed them all so far, and the next update will generate some more.

I have all the imp levels except overbridge, as I refuse to spend money on a game to buy bux. It also seems quite fruitless according to what others on this site have said re spending lots of bux but no new levels